# React: why does the whole array rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, rerender

I have an array that is mapped inside a react component and creates another react component for each item like this:

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

const Parent: FC = () => {

  const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([0,1,2,3])

  const addToArray = (item: number) => {
    const newArray = [...testArray, item]
    setTestArray(newArray)
  }

  return <>
        <button onClick={() => addToArray(testArray.length)}>Add</button>
        {
            testArray.map(item => {
                return <ChildItem
                    value={item}
                    key={uuidv4()}
                ></ChildItem>
            })
        }
        </>    
}
export default Parent
```

The `addToArray` function does just add an item to the array. To my understanding, react should only render the added item and not rerender all other items, as the props of those have not changed.

However, it seems that all children are rerender, when the function is called. In the ChildItem, a console.log() runs for every item. I only want it to run for the item just being created.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

const ChildItem: FC<{ value: number }> = (props) => {

    console.log('render', props.value)

    return <>
        <li>{props.value}</li>
    </>
}

export default ChildItem
```

Does anybody see, what I am missing here? I have also tried to make the Child Item a memo Component (`export default memo(ChildItem)`), which doesn't make a difference. I'm using react 18.2.0

Comment: Because the `key` prop has been changed. Every time the `Parent` component is rendered, the map function will be called for each item, and the `uuidv4()` will be called to produce a new key

Comment: Does not depend on that. I could also call the Child like this: ` <ChildItem
                    value={item}
                    key={item}
                ></ChildItem>` with the same result.

Comment: Take a look at this article. Looks like useCallback() might be your friend for this problem. https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-list-rerender/

Comment: Thanks for the article, that was what i needed. It's not only a static key and memo, but also useCallback and the use of functional state updates that are important here.  I'm surprised how hard it is to achieve that behaviour in React.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior that React component re-renders themselves and all their child components when the state is changed.

In your case, you could use `React.memo` to memoize the child component, but you cannot use uuidv4 as a key because it generates new uuid every time the parent component re-renders. That causes the child component's key to be different in each render cycle (=the child component is remounted on every render).

So, wrap your child component in memo

```
const ChildItem = React.memo(({value}) => {
```

And use a dirrefend key value

```
 return <ChildItem
           value={item}
           key={item}
        ></ChildItem>
```

That should do the trick.